# Отбор записей по первой букве?

Tags: ms-word

Как выполнить отбор по полю для слов которые начинаются с определенной буквы?. У меня задание выполнить отбор по марке машины, которая начинается с буквы Т, я не понимаю как это делается, нет условия "содержит"[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: там нигде тип поля не настраивается, что это Строка а не число? обычно для текстовых фильтров имеются "начинается с" и упомянутое "содержит"

Comment: это строка, но я не понимаю как сделать отбор записей по букве Т